# How can I unplug videi connector with plastic clip?

Tags: connector

Im working on an asus pc 1101 ha. This cable seems to lead to the monitor. Does this thing even have a name? I dont know. I just want to know how it works and unplug it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The black plastic thing is there to help you disconnect it. Pull it upwards.

If you're not sure what to do, try to find a service manual for the computer you're working on or similar one. It's usually a good idea to do this *before* starting the disassembly.

Comment: https://www.asus.com/supportonly/Eee%20PC%201101HA/HelpDesk_Manual/ is your friend